# Duplicate Declaration of method' startCameraControllerfromViewController:usingDelegate:'

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have two UI Buttons in my view controller, and an imageview. One button has the user pick a picture from the photo library and add it to the UIImage. The other has the user take a new picture and show it in the UIimage.

The libraryButton and actions all work, however when I add the cameraButton code I get an error since I'm using the same "startcameracontrollerfromviewcontroller" My question is can I simply change this to startcameracontrolfromviewcontroller? or is there something else I would have to change.

```
#pragma mark - Button Actions

- (IBAction)libraryButton:(id)sender {
    [self startCameraControllerFromViewController:self usingDelegate:self];
}

#pragma mark - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate methods

- (BOOL) startCameraControllerFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate {
    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO) || (delegate == nil) || (controller == nil))
        return NO;

    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    cameraUI.delegate = delegate;
    [controller presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:nil];
    return YES;
}

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage * image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    _imageView.image = image;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}




#pragma mark - Camera Button

- (IBAction)cameraButton:(id)sender {
    [self startCameraControllerFromViewController:self usingDelegate:self];
}


#pragma mark - Camera Delegate methods

- (BOOL) startCameraControllerFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate {
    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO) || (delegate == nil) || (controller == nil))
        return NO;

    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    cameraUI.delegate = delegate;
    [controller presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:nil];
    return YES;
}

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage * image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    _imageView.image = image;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}




@end
```

Comment: First it seems both methods startCameraControllerFromViewController:usingDelegate: are identical. Use the same method for both operations. If both button do the same, opening image picker. Use only one button in your code.

Comment: Yes they both open image picker, one to the camera roll and the other to take picture. Would it still be best to make it one button in that case?

Comment: sure. you are duplicating your code. or you code use sender.tag to determine if open image picker with camera, or image picker with library.

Comment: Okay, now with one button how do I specify library or take picture? Once that button is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the same method from each **IBAction** passing it a different value that will be used to determine the image pickers source type - *(for this example I'm not passing in the presenting view controller or delegate, but this could be easily adapted to implement)*

```
- (IBAction)libraryButton:(id)sender {
    [self showImagePickerForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
}

- (IBAction)cameraButton:(id)sender {
    [self showImagePickerForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
}

- (void)showImagePickerForSourceType:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType {
    // start config here....

    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    // set the source type here
    imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;

    // do any extra setting up... present controller...
}
```

I suggest looking at this sample code provided by Apple - [Using UIImagePickerController to Select Pictures and Take Photos](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

Comment: One more question, I am doing this for ipad. Is there anything I need to adjust?

Comment: You can't present this modally on iPad if you are selecting photos from the library. You need to present the picker inside a UIPopoverController

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, do you have any sample code for that